# multiple radio button asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button, html-helper

Hi i having issues with multiple radio buttons in the view created by a foreach loop are all grouped as one, so i can only click one no matter how many are displayed (normally 10+), any help would be helpfully.

View

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
     foreach (var question in Model.Question)
     {             
           <div id ="quest1">
                <div id ="questText">
                    <div class="cat">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => question.Category.CategoryName)-@Html.DisplayFor(model => question.SubCategory.SubCategoryName)
                    </div>                      
                    <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => question.QuestionText)           
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-label"> 
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => question.QuestionAnsNum,1,new { @sytle = "width:5px;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model =>question.A)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => question.QuestionAnsNum,2,new { @sytle = "width:5px;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model =>question.B)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => question.QuestionAnsNum,3,new { @sytle = "width:5px;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model =>question.C)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => question.QuestionAnsNum,4,new { @sytle = "width:5px;background:none;border:none" })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model =>question.D)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <br />
        }
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: If you want them to behave like a set of radio buttons where only one can be checked at a time, you need to give them the same ``name`` attribute in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the same name attribute for all elements within each group.
Also, fix the **"sytle"** word :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply guys, i tried your suggestions but still same issue. Displaying 5 questions with 4 radio buttons each, still only able to click one button of the lot.

Comment: @GlenGreenwood huh, so you need to set same name property for those which you want to be grouped. So set name=q1 for 4 items of question #1, name=q2 for itema of question #2 etc.

Comment: @GlenGreenwood did that help? If so, pleace accept the answer

Comment: Thank you jim, yeah had to give each group an individual name loaded in a foreach in the controller and another field in a table but it works, he a sample of the code for anyone who has similar issues.                    `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => question.QuestionAnsNum, 1, new {Name=@Html.DisplayFor(model => question.QuestionNum).ToHtmlString()})
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model =>question.A)`